# Creating dynamic divs with a close button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a file upload system with every selected file showing nicely in a div.

```
<div id="selected-files">
   <div id="selected-file">
      <svg>static file icon</svg>
      <span>file name</span>
      <svg>close icon</svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery logic is that it clones the "selected-file" div and modifies the contents accordingly, including adding a custom ID `*close-icon-id-x*` to the `*Close Icon*` svg.

But I'm not sure how to call a `$("#close-icon-id-x")` so I can close the cloned div accordingly. The current `id-x` is the amount of files added to the input, and this logic wouldn't work properly.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
var selected_file = $(".selected-file").clone();

$($(selected_file).children()[1]).attr("id","my-custom-id-" + id-x);
$(selected_file).insertAfter('.selected-file');
```

Comment: if the close button is inside the cloned div, I would give it a class and use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) making sure it closed the parent / ancestor div of itself on click

Comment: `$(document).on("click",".selected-cancel", function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
 });`



This works, surprised I didn't think about it. Is this the right approach?

Comment: yeah, that's what I would do, perhaps not bind it to the document though, I'd bind it to the `selected-files` div as that is not going to be removed and should be there when your jquery initialises, but that's just personal preference